# C# Count if Field Exists

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Below is a script making an API call which retrieves some ReportIDs (from a database table), passes them through a method which will run them individually, and finally see if each contains the field, Name_First.

What I need help with is creating a count that will tell me how many reports contain the field Name_First, how many don't, and what's the percentage out of all reports having the field, Name_First.

Currently, the script queries two ReportIDs (12300,12301) for testing. One report has the field Name_First in it and the other one doesn't. From the foreach loop I've written, I'm aiming to count every time there is a null and every time there isn't, get a total, and just divide the not null count by the sum of both. However, when I run this script, the console at

```
                Console.WriteLine(total);
                Console.WriteLine(total_noFirstName);
                Console.WriteLine(total_FirstName);
```

returns values of 0, 0, and 0. I think I'm having a scope issue here, but I'm not really sure. If I could receive some help solving this, I'd very much appreciate it.

Thank you!

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace NameFirstSearch
{
   class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        const string username = "Username";
        const string password = "Password";



        const string baseUrl = "https://test.com/rest/services/";


        const string queryString = "query?q=Select * From Report Where ReportID in (12300,12301)";
        const string queryNameFirst = "getreport/";

        var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(username + ":" + password));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", auth);

        //GetReports(client, queryString).Wait();
        var  reportsList = GetReports(client, queryString).Result;
        GetNameFirst(client, queryNameFirst, reportsList).Wait();

        Console.ReadLine();

    }



    static async Task<List<Properties>> GetReports(HttpClient client, string queryString)
    {

        List<Properties> result = new List<Properties>();

        var response = await client.GetAsync(queryString);

        // Check for a successfull result
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Properties>>(json);
        }
        else
        {
            // Error code returned
            Console.WriteLine("No records found on first method.");
        }

        return result;

    }


    static async Task GetNameFirst(HttpClient client, string queryNameFirst, List<Properties> results)
    {
        string reportType = ".json";

        foreach (var item in results)
        {
            var output = await client.GetAsync(queryNameFirst + item.ReportID + reportType);


            if (output.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var allText = await output.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FirstName>>(allText);

                var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);

                Console.WriteLine(test);

                int total_FirstName = 0;
                int total_noFirstName = 0;
                int total = total_FirstName + total_noFirstName;
                foreach (var split in fields)
                {

                    if (split.Name_First != null)
                    {
                        total_FirstName++;

                    }
                    else if (split.Name_First == null)
                    {

                        total_noFirstName++;

                    }

                }
                Console.WriteLine(total);
                Console.WriteLine(total_noFirstName);
                Console.WriteLine(total_FirstName);

            }
            else
            {
                // Error code returned
                Console.WriteLine("No records found on second method.");
            }

        }

    }



}
}
```

---

Class Properties

```
int ReportID {get; set;}
```

---

Class FirstName

```
string Name_First {get; set;}
```

---

Results at Console.WriteLine(test);

```
 [{"Name_First":"Mario"}]
 [{"Name_First":null}]
```

---

Results for Console.WriteLine(allText);

```
 [{"Name_First":"Mario","Entry_ID":"72313"}]
 [{"Name_Last":"Rincon Recio","Entry_ID":"72313"}]
```

Comment: That's a first-class SQL vulnerability right there. It hardly qualifies as SQL "injection" because a complete, harmful query could be provided without having to employ any injection tricks.

Comment: Well `total` is always going to be zero because you set it to `0+0`

Comment: I believe that newing up an HttpClient like that is not best practice.  See the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient) for their suggestion.

Comment: Rather then writing your own code I'd suggest using Linq.  It has a count method that does what you need.-  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Can you show what `allText` contains, because what you've shown is not the serialization of a `List<FirstName>` it should look like `[{"Name_First":"Mario"},{"Name_First":null}]`

Comment: @iakobski      Sure. Refer to question.

Comment: @iakobski - i was confused too. but I think its the outer loop causing Console.WriteLine(test); to be called twice, rather than a collection with 2 items. To OP - you should place a break point at foreach (var split in fields) and inspect all the local variables. (i had added this as an answer, but should've been a comment)

Comment: OK, I get it now. Each of your lists in `results` has just one item. You should declare and initialise `total_FirstName` and `total_noFirstName` outside the loop over results, at the beginning. You are setting them to zero every time through the loop. Similarly, declare `total` outside the loop at the bottom and do the sum, then print out the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep a count of things in a loop, you need to declare the counter variables outside of the loop, otherwise they get reinitialised. Using your data from the question, the relevant loop should look like this:

```
    List<string> allTexts = new List<string>
    { @"[{""Name_First"":""Mario"",""Entry_ID"":""72313""}]",
      @"[{""Name_Last"":""Rincon Recio"",""Entry_ID"":""72313""}]" };

    int total_FirstName = 0;
    int total_noFirstName = 0;

    foreach(var allText in allTexts)
    {
        var fields = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FirstName>>(allText);
        var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);
        Console.WriteLine(test);

        foreach (var split in fields)
        {
            if (split.Name_First != null)
            {
                total_FirstName++;
            }
            else
            {
                total_noFirstName++;
            }
        }
    }
    int total = total_FirstName + total_noFirstName;
    Console.WriteLine(total);
    Console.WriteLine(total_noFirstName);
    Console.WriteLine(total_FirstName);
```

Output:

```
 [{"Name_First":"Mario"}]
 [{"Name_First":null}]
 2
 1
 1
```

Comment: Sorry for not checking back with you.  I was able to take what you originally posted in the comment section and apply it to my code. Essentially, what you provided above is what I did. I now get the desired results out of this test scenario (2 for total, 1 for total_FirstName, 0.5 as percentage value).  I forgot   to reply back because I got so excited I started running the script now targeting all reports (1620) instead of these two only. Sadly I haven't able to get the script to run through all of them since I get a Task error midway, and I'm trying to think how to go about it